# What are differences between $id=(int)@$_REQUEST['id']; and $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

Tags: php, int

What do @ and (int) do in the following.

```
$id=(int)@$_REQUEST['id'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ supressess errors, and (int) casts to the type Integer.

1. [Error-control Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)
2. [Type-Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: Do you know what the value of `$id` would be if `$_REQUEST` has no value with key `'id'`?

Comment: it would raise a notice, more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

(int) is converting whatever the value of $_REQUEST['id']  into an integer (this is called casting).